# run Java serial program in a terminal loop

Tags: java, loops, terminal

I have a java app (serial code) and I want to run it 100 times in a loop using the linux terminal. Later on I want to collect the results produced by the program.

How to run it in a loop?

Comment: And do you also have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a shell script and run it with terminal

```
#!/bin/bash
max=10
for i in `seq 2 $max`
do
    java -jar path/to/jar/file.jar
done
```

Comment: is it possible not to create a shell script but just execute a command?

Comment: I got it: `for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do java -cp 'path/to/jar' program; done`

Comment: yes you can. 

for((i=0;i<10;i++)); do java -jar path/to/jar/file.jar; done